# What can I use like a replacement of the notification area?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Well , I used both codes below , also I used dconf-editor to tweak the panel.

I Tried to set the code to one program or two , and 'all'.

But the problem is that sometimes(not always) I can't click on the sound indicator or network manager or any indicator (Except the Me menu, the messaging menu, and the shutdown menu).

1. `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`
2. `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'YOUR_APPLICATION']"`

So I want something to replace this problem please.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "problem" is a bug, and has nothing to do with the notification area. Sometimes the indicators do not take clicks, why, I'm not 100% sure. Fortunately, there are two ways around it:

1. You can click on an indicator that works, and then move the mouse toward the other indicator that you want, and it will open it.
2. You can restart unity: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> - `unity` - <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Ohh I see. 
For the first step , yes it works. and the second worked and then return to the same issue. Ubuntu 11.04 is awesome , but this is bothering me.They will fix this bug right ?

Comment: @binarylie: I believe so, I would suggest adding some voice to it on launchpad (`ubuntu-bug unity`), your help in getting to the bottom of it would be greatly appreciated.